# LodePNG crashes when encoding PNG files with size greater than 15000 * 15000 pixels

Tags: c, png

I've been using LodePNG's `lodepng_encode24_file` to encode some 24-bit RGB image files, and it has worked wonderfully so far. However, I noticed that it appears to crash when I feed it a dataset larger than 15360*15360 pixels in size (14336*14336 pixel images get encoded fine).

A minimal example of this behavior for the 32-bit case (where the maximum size before crashing is slightly lower) can be obtained by simply replacing the line

```
  unsigned width = 512, height = 512;
```

with

```
  unsigned width = 1024*14, height = 1024*14;
```

in [LodePNG's example_encode.c file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lvandeve/lodepng/master/example_encode.c), and executing it.

I previously had issues with C code crashing because I was allocating large arrays to stack memory (whose maximum size is generally somewhere around 2MB) instead of heap memory, so as a new user of C, my first instinct was to see if there is an upper limit on heap memory size.

However, [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12687474/3051203), there is no limit on heap memory, so something else must be going wrong.

My second guess was that the crash was due to an inherent limitation on the maximum image dimensions supported by the PNG format itself. However, [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4109505/3051203) and the comment below it, the maximum file size supported by PNG is on the order of 4,000,000,000 * 4,000,000,000 pixels, so this is also not the culprit.

Does anyone have a guess as to what might be going wrong? Is anyone else able to reproduce this error when they try it?

**EDIT**: As far as RAM consumption is concerned, I have 8GB RAM, and subtracting the hardware-reserved, in-use, modified and standby memory (terms used by Windows Resource Monitor utility) I have about 4GB RAM free when doing the computation. For a 32-bit image of 15000*15000 size, less than 1GB would be needed. Likewise, when I successfully encode 14000*14000 24-bit images, my free RAM never drops below 3GB at any point of the encoding process, so I don't think RAM running out is the problem.

Comment: Of course there's a limit to heap memory, several in fact. First there's the limit of what your system can handle, like for example a 32-bit system can only address up to 4GB. Then there the actual amount of physical and swap space available to the system, less the memory needed for the operating system, and all other processes running on your system. And finally, there's a limit in that when you allocate memory, all of it needs to be one big contiguous block, and if no such big block is available then the allocation fails.

Comment: Depending on how you generate your image, you might want to encode it line per line - so that you only need to have one row in memory. PNG format is straightforward for this (leaving aside interlaced PNG) and libpng allows that mode or writing (and reading), see eg [png_write_row()](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Desktop-generic/LSB-Desktop-generic/libpng12.png.write.row.1.html). (I do the same in my Java lib [PNGJ](https://code.google.com/p/pngj/)). I don't know about LodePNG.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Thanks for the reply. In the case of my system, I have 8GB RAM, and subtracting the hardware-reserved, in-use, modified and standby memory (terms used by Windows Resource Monitor utility) I have about 4GB RAM free when doing the computation. For a 32-bit image of 15000*15000 size, less than 1GB would be needed. Likewise, when I successfully encode 14000*14000 24-bit images, my free RAM never drops below 3GB at any point of the encoding process, so I don't think RAM running out is the problem. I don't know anything about the contiguity of my RAM, though.

Comment: Couldn't it just be a bug in the code provided by LodePNG?

Comment: Seems like a memory fragmentation issue, or LodePNG implementation limitation/bug. Just tried saving 16384x16384 24-bit image using libpng, works fine.

Comment: @alk: When you say "code provided by LodePNG", do you mean the `example_encode.c` file, or do you mean LodePNG itself? The `example_encode.c` file executes properly for all image sizes below around 13312*13312, and for me it crashes around the 14000*14000 mark and above, so I think the issue isn't with the example file, but rather with LodePNG itself, or with something going wrong with my computer.

Comment: @user2802841: LOL, I guess my computer just sucks, haha :) Thanks for trying to verify it and share your results.

Comment: @leonbloy: Yeah, if I can't figure out why this is crashing then I'll probably just do what you say and break the encoding into smaller, more manageable pieces.

Comment: I meant LodePNG itself.

Comment: @user2802841: You did not use LodePNG, did you?

Comment: In which does the code crash when you run your test?

Comment: @alk That is correct, I tried using reference library [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/), doesn't seem to have any trouble writing images even well over 1GB in size. In OPs case I would try running the code under debugger to see where exactly it fails.

Comment: I strongly assume the observed behaviour is bug in LodePNG. I just compiled the current version, created the example program as per the OP and run it. It did crash. Runnng it under Valgrind revealed memory issues inside the LodePNG code.

Comment: The PNG size limits are 2Gx2G, not 4Gx4G, but still plenty larger than your images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are underestimating how much memory your program uses. Assuming you are on Windows then you probably only have 2 GB of memory available for a process to use (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639540/how-much-memory-can-a-32-bit-process-access-on-a-64-bit-operating-system)). You then allocate a big 882 MB chunk for your 14336x14336 image. The LodePNG code then does more allocations most likely equal to or greater than this image size.

I only traced the [LodePNG code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lvandeve/lodepng/master/lodepng.cpp) manually but it seems to create a buffer in memory and write to that buffer in chunks. It does a minimum resize when reallocating (in `lodepng_chunk_append()`, only enough to hold the data plus 12 bytes) which means it will have to do a lot of reallocations. This may (or eventually will) fragment the memory to a point where a very large buffer is not available.

Even if the heap memory is not fragmented think about what might happen when you try to `realloc()` a 800MB buffer to a 801MB one. It might work if the heap manager is "smart" but a naive one will require a total of 1601MB...which is not available if your heap is 2000MB in size and you've already used 822MB of it.

A lot (most) of this is conjecture but you can do some tests yourself to simulate allocating and reallocating several large chunks of memory to see if you can reproduce the out of memory situation.

**Appendum:** While the above may be true it is actually not the cause of the crash in this case. From actually running and tracing the code the issue is line 5558 in [LodePng.c](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lvandeve/lodepng/master/lodepng.cpp):

```
size_t size = (w * h * lodepng_get_bpp(&info.color) + 7) / 8;
```

This calculation results in an integer overflow when `w * h` is greater than 178,956,970 when `lodepng_get_bpp()` returns 24. For a square image this is 13378 x 13378. This causes the output buffer to be allocated the incorrect size and thus a buffer overflow when it is later written to.

A quick fix would be to change this line to:

```
 size_t size = (size_t) ((unsigned long long) w * h * lodepng_get_bpp(&info.color) / 8 + 1);
```

although I'm not sure this will work correctly for all BPP values and it still has an overflow issue albeit at a larger size. I would suggest contacting the author of LodePNG to implement a proper fix.

Comment: Yikes - introduce a float? That has far less precision than an int. A better move would be changing the parentheses: `((lodepng_get_bpp(&info.color) + 7) / 8)`, although this is only a partial fix, as it will not allow `MAX_INT * MAX_INT` images with more than a 1-byte color spec. (It may be beyond what the author of LodePng imagined for typical use.)

Comment: Nonono `float`, at least for a 64bit system using `long` would do the job: `size_t size = (w * h * (long) lodepng_get_bpp(&info.color) + 7) / 8;`

Comment: @Jongware: Your proposal is not an exact replacment for the original code.

Comment: Using float does feel a bit "wrong". Casting up to a 64-bit integer and then back down to 32-bit would be ideal.

Comment: @alk: right-o. I was assuming `bpp` could safely be downscaled, but PNG allows *lower* bit depths than as well. The maximum "raw" size can be 2³¹ * 2³¹ ([earlier SO question on the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109447/file-format-limits-in-pixel-size-for-png-images)), with the bit depth up to a staggering 64-bit RGBA. ...Well beyond my system's current capabilities.